# pandoc converting tex to docx with references - not enclosed in parentheses / brackets

Tags: pandoc, bibtex

I am trying to convert a pretty basic latex file to docx format using pandoc and am having a slight issue with the in-text citation not being enclosed in parentheses `()`

tex doc minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\cite{hendrickson_resource_2000}

\end{document}
```

And the bib file looks like:

```
@article{hendrickson_resource_2000,
    title = {Resource use and environmental emissions of {US} construction sectors},
    volume = {126},
    issn = {0733-9364},
    number = {1},
    journal = {Journal of Construction Engineering and Management},
    author = {Hendrickson, Chris and Horvath, Arpad},
    year = {2000},
    pages = {38--44}
},
```

Using an APA citation style, such as: https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/apa-5th-edition.csl I would expect that the in-text citation would be:

```
(Hendrickson & Horvath, 2000)
```

...but instead it is:

```
Hendrickson & Horvath (2000)
```

I have tried multiple conversion paths, styles and command line options and am not getting any change in the in-text citation despite changes in the overall reference list / bibliography.

My current attempt is:

```
pandoc -o test.docx test.tex --bibliography References.bibtex --csl apa5.csl
```

How do I get the intended enclosed in-text citation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `\cite{hendrickson_resource_2000}`, perhaps you could try `\citep{hendrickson_resource_2000}`?

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/wSdhT4GxEog/1vDHtEOwfUYJ for some possibly related info.

Comment: Bingo. That did it.